# issue looping through SQL table C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, loops

My application is reading off a SQL query table and matching and displaying values in certain fields in a listview. My query SQL table looks like this

```
+--------------+---------+-------+----------+--------+
| process name | subtask | total | employee |  date  |
+--------------+---------+-------+----------+--------+
| process 1    | sub1    |     1 |     1111 | 01-May |
| process 2    |         |     1 |     2222 | 05-May |
| process 3    |         |     1 |     3333 | 10-May |
| process 4    |         |     1 |     4444 | 07-May |
+--------------+---------+-------+----------+--------+
```

I have run into a problem. I have noticed by stepping through my loops (using messegebox) that process 1 is displayed in my messagebox multiple times (in `MessageBox.Show(dr[0].ToString());`) when it should only be displayed once and when the loop gets to process 4 the messagebox displays process 4 (in (in `MessageBox.Show(dr[0].ToString());`)) then the loop stops and thus does not grab the total, employee and date values. How can I fix this.

```
         DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        var startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
        var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);


        string[,] report = new string[,] { {"process 1", "sub1", "3", "0",  "", "" },
       {"process 2", "", "3", "0", "", "" },
       {"process 3", "", "3", "0", "", "" }
        *** there are multiple entries in this array *****
       }  

    string totalsquery = "select Process_Name, Sub_Process1_Name, count(id) as total, Completed_By_Employee_Number, max(Refresh_Date)  from testDB.dbo.Quality_Data_Master  where Refresh_Date between '" + startDate + "' and '" + endDate + "' group by Process_Name, Sub_Process1_Name,  Completed_By_Employee_Number, Refresh_Date";


  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(totalsquery, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ada.Fill(dt);

        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Process Name", 250);
        listView1.Columns.Add(" Sub Task", 200);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Target", 45, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Total", 40, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Employee", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Date", 100);


        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {


            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];

            //MessageBox.Show(dr.ToString());
            for (int j = 0; j < report.GetLength(0); j++)
            {

                if (report[j, 0].Equals(dr[0].ToString()))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(dr[0].ToString());
                    if (report[j, 1].Equals(dr[1].ToString()))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(dr[1].ToString());

                        report[j, 3] = (Int32.Parse(report[j, 3]) + (int)dr[2]).ToString();

                        MessageBox.Show(dr[2].ToString());

                        report[j, 4] = report[j, 4] + dr[3].ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show(dr[3].ToString());

                        report[j, 5] = report[j, 5] + dr[4].ToString();



                        MessageBox.Show(dr[4].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }





        String[] temp = new String[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < report.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            temp[0] = report[i, 0].ToString();
            temp[1] = report[i, 1].ToString();
            temp[2] = report[i, 2].ToString();
            temp[3] = report[i, 3].ToString();
            temp[4] = report[i, 4].ToString();
            temp[5] = report[i, 5].ToString();
            //temp[6] = report[i, 6].ToString();

            ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem(temp);
            listView1.Items.Add(listItem);

        }

            con.Close();
```

Comment: Your whole loop works with the variable "report" which is not defined anywhere, nor is your query shown anywhere. So it seems this is where to start searching. Did you check the contens of "report"?

Comment: the report is a array I will add that to the code I am showing  thanks

Comment: I don't know if you pasted the complete`report` variable, this is what I'm looking at: `string[,] report = new string[,] { {"process 1", "sub1", "3", "0", "", "" },`    I can only assume you forgot the last `}`, on which case you will have a two dimensional array but while one dimension has 1 item (an array of 6 items), the other one is empty. I think to fix that you have to change `report.GetLength(0)` to `report.GetLength(1)`

Comment: Please consider refactoring your SQL code to avoid concatenating strings. Use [parameterization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx) instead, as it can help not only avoid typos but it can protect you from possible SQL Injections.

Comment: yes sorry there are multiple variables in that array I tried to mention that with the <code> //there are multiple entries in this array </code> and I did forget to put the closing <code> } </code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recomend to refactor your code, also.

Instead of using ListView, look at DataGridView.

With DataGridView you can simple do:

```
// dataGridView defined at design
// more info on [msdn][1] pages
DataTable dt = GetDataTable(...);
dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```